# How can I do 2 tasks at the same time?

Tags: c#

Im trying to get a function and a return at go at the same time, or i need the function to run after the return.

```cs
private void GiveBackInput(string s)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(125);
            SendKeys.SendWait(s);
        }
private bool idontrememberthisname(string hexcode){
 ... if (...)
         {    
          GiveBackInput("A");
          return true;
         }
//i need it to be like this
... if (...)
        {    
         return true;
         GiveBackInput("A");
         }}
```

edit: forgot to put that the if statement is in a different method

Comment: What do you mean by that `get a function and a return at go at the same time,`. It would be better to explain further.

Comment: i need it to return instantly but the Thread.sleep in the function makes it wait. I just need it to return some way without waiting but also do the function.

Comment: create a Task to perform the action and fire it inside the function, then return

Comment: no, it always has to sleep, and Democrats i have no idea what you meant.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming

Comment: Task taskA = new Task( () => return true); is impossible

Comment: @Rubiksmaster02 It is very possible to create a task that returns a bool.  Your syntax is invalid.

Comment: how would i do this?

Comment: Remove the `return` keyword and strongly-type the task by specifying its generic type parameter.  `Task taskA = new Task<bool>(() => true);`  You should spend some time reviewing tutorials on tasks.

Comment: does that return bool to the method though?

Comment: It does if you await it. **Read some tutorials** on tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a new task or new thread.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Task taskA = new Task( () => return true); is impossible